# Bloquear celdas de grid en extjs?

Tags: extjs, grid

tengo una grid en extjs 6, la cual tiene un horario de trabajo.

Si le coloco a un textfield 22 horas, deberia dejarme habilitado para la edicion en el grid solo la mañana, pero si dejo 44, todo el dia.

El grid contiene 5 columna: Dia:, (Mañana) Entrada, Salida, (Tarde)Entrada , Salida.

[image: Grilla]

Cada columna tiene  celdas q son como combobox con un valor minimo y maximo, la idea es dejar vacios los de la tarde cuando active 22 horas y q no se puedan editar.

Como bloqueo una una celda, o una columna de celdas en extjs?

Este es el diseño de una columna (Jornada Mañana):

```
 xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                        menuDisabled: true,
                        text: 'Jornada Mañana',
                        columns: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                renderer: 'renderHora1',
                                itemId: 'mycolumn17',
                                resizable: false,
                                dataIndex: 'entrada_manana',
                                menuDisabled: true,
                                text: 'Entrada',
                                editor: {
                                    xtype: 'timefield',
                                    itemId: 'mytimefield',
                                    hideLabel: true,
                                    format: 'H:i',
                                    maxValue: '10:00',
                                    minValue: '6:00',
                                    submitFormat: 'H:i',
                                    listeners: {
                                        select: 'onTimefieldSelect'
                                    }
```

Por ejemplo yo sé que si a la columna le quito el apartado editor: ya no se podria editar, pero no se como hacerlo optimamente.

Alguna idea de como podria bloquear unas celdas en particular?

Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: ¿Al decir bloquear te refieres a que no se puedan editar? es decir, ¿Bloquear la edición?

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar tpl o puedes utlizar el render del control de la celda y evaluar el dato que llega en el método.

Referencias:

- http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#method-onRender
- http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-renderTpl

Comment: Quizás, para darle más valor a tu respuesta puedas agregar un pequeño ejemplo de código.